# Can't sign in to Apple Music, TV or Podcast on Mac

Tags: itunes, mac, apple-music

I recently did a clean install of macOS Catalina on my MacBook Air and since I can't sign in my Apple Music account in Music App. Neither I can connect to TV although I don't have a subscription contrary to Apple Music. Same thing for Podcast, I can't sign in.

My Apple Music account works fine on the beta website or on my phone and every other iCloud service is fine too.

I tried deleting the full library, rebooting, login out and in again to iCloud and other things like that.

Sometimes I got various error ranging from 11556 to "not available in your country".

Any advice or solution?

Answer (score 1):

It magically solved itself after few days.